# Heaviside Function Induced Measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given the Heaviside function,
$$H := \begin{cases} 1 \quad \, x\geq0 \\
0 \quad \, x < 0
\end{cases}$$

We can induce a measure that behaves in such a way so that all subsets of $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ are measurable and have non-zero measure iff $0 \in A$. The measure induced coming from the normal measure induced from monotonically increasing functions.

Now, I have two questions. When we integrate any function $f \in \mathscr{L}(\mu_H)$ w.r.t. $\mu_H$, we get

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f \, \mu_H = f(0).$$

The first thing I need to do is to show that there does not exist a function $g$ such that (for borel measurable subsets) $$\mu_H (A) = \int_A g \, dm$$ where $m$ is the lebesgue measure. Clearly no. For a function to have non-zero Lebesgue Integral w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, it must be non-zero on a set with non-zero Lebesgue measure. So, such a $g$ would have to satisfy 
$$\mu_\alpha (A) = \int_A g \, dm >0 $$ if $0 \in A$ and $0$ otherwise. This is impossible, since $m(\{0\}) =0$, so if $$\int_A g \, dm > 0,$$ then $$\int_{A} g \, dm = \int_{A \setminus \{0\}} g \, dm > 0,$$

Now my other question is about the fact that there seems to be something going here that I can't quite put my finger on. I know the the $\delta$ distribution is the distributional derivative of the Heaviside function, and that the integral against $\delta_0$ picks out the function's value at $0$. So, why is it that when I integrate a function w.r.t. the measure induced by the heaviside function, it's as if I'm integrating against its distributional derivative? That is,

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f \, \mu_H = f(0) = \int_\mathbb{R} f H' \, dm$$

Is there a general fact here?

Comment: Your first argument seems to be on the right path. You can integrate the characteristic function on $\{0\}$, denote this as $\mathbf{1}_0$ with respect to $\mu_H$ and you will get 1 back. However, for the measure $\mu_g$ induced by the unsigned measurable function $g$, one can prove that for unsigned measurable $h$ we have that $\int h \ d\mu_g = \int gh \ dm$. (Use monotone convergence theorem). Clearly, no matter what the $g$, if $h =  \mathbf{1}_0$, $\int gh \ dm = 0$. since $\{0\}$ has Lebesque measure zero. Apologies if this is a bit convoluted...

Comment: @user137769 What is not rigorous about simply using the fact that $\psi(A) = \int_A g \, dm$ is a measure and just writing $A$ as $A \setminus \{1\} \cup \{1\}$?

Comment: Why has no one pointed out yet that your function $H$ isn't the Heaviside function? Your $H$ is almost everywhere equal to 0, whereas the Heaviside function is 0 for $x < 0$ and 1 for $x > 0$. Correcting this might clarify some things. (For instance, the delta function is *not* the distributional derivative of your $H$!).

Comment: @AustinA. Typo. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, this argument looks like it works. I did not understand what you were reasoning above in the first post because of the 1 instead of the 0 initially.

Comment: @user137769 My apologies, our professor made a typo on the homework putting the jump at $1$, so I've been typing it wrong. the $1$ above should be a $0$.

Comment: As to the second question in your original post, you are correct. There is a general fact here. If you look at the Wiki page for the [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) you'll see that there is a correspondence between $\int f d\mu_{g}$ and $\int f g' d\mu$. In particular, if $g \in C^2$, then this is true with Riemann integrals. I don't have the necessary references to look up the broader statement, but you're definitely on to something.

Comment: @AustinA. Ah it would be clear from that definition, by the MVT, we'd have $g'(c)m([x_i,x_{i-1}])$ for some $c \in (x_i,x_{i-1})$... is this in essence all such an induced measure is? The stiltjes variant of the Riemann integral?